# How to make Hybris CMSParagraphComponent print variable value

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

Is there a way to make CMSParagraphComponent print variable values?

On my controller I have something like this:

```
model.addAttribute("isInvoiceAvailable", currentBaseStore.isAccountPaymentAvailable());

return ControllerConstants.Views.Pages.Account.PAYMENT_OPTIONS_LANDING_PAGE;
```

My jsp look like this:

```
    <cms:pageSlot position="Section1" var="feature">
        <c:set var="adjustPosition" value="${true}" />
        <cms:component component="${feature}" element="div" class="span-24 section1Template7 cms_disp-img_slot"/>
    </cms:pageSlot>
```

The above mentioned component is a CMSParagraphComponent.

The CMSParagraphComponent  content look like this:

```
UPDATE CMSParagraphComponent ; $contentCV[unique=true] ; uid[unique=true]     ; content[lang=$lang]
 ;                         ; paymentOptionsParagraph ; "
 <h3>Payment Options</h3>
 <br>
 ${isInvoiceAvailable}
 $isInvoiceAvailable
 <h4>Credit card</h4>
 <br>
 <p>
    
    MasterCard, Visa
 </p>"
```

And when the page loads it's printing the content as if there were no variables, like this:
[image]

Is there a way to make the component print some variable value from the page contenxt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**CMSParagraphComponent** is rendered using **CMSParagraphComponentRenderer.java**, so the [Expression Language](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info) is not available at the moment of the rendering, and as a result, what you are trying to do is not possible.

I think for your use case a JSPIncludeComponent is more appropriate, another solution would be to create your own component type and use a JSP file to render it.